# JavaFX8: CheckboxListCell in ListView unchecks cells when scrolling

Tags: java, listview, javafx, checkbox, event-handling

I'll try keep it short, more info at the bottom.

I am struggling to get a ListView with CheckBoxes working. I have a GUI application, and want a neat compact view so that a user can select multiple options from a list while "editing" their "profile" information without the list taking up a whole screen. So I opted for a ListView with CheckBoxListCell. I am able to initialize the list fine and checking/unchecking options triggers the wanted event, but when I scroll down the list and scroll back up the previously checked box is unchecked, and no event is triggered indicating this isn't a change event that happens when scrolling. Is this a bug or am I missing something in my initialization?

Here is the code relevant to initializing the ListView:

```
private void setOrgansListed(Boolean editing) {
    ObservableList<OrganEnum> listedOrgs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    if (editing) {
        System.out.println("Editing");
        listedOrgs.setAll(OrganEnum.values());
        organsListed.setItems(listedOrgs);
        organsListed.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(param -> {
            BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
            observable.addListener(((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
                GuiUndoController.add(new Tuple<>("organ", organsListed));
            }));
            return observable;
        }));
```

[This is a picture of the ListView in the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVsq1.png)

Extended info:
I am fairly new to Java and JavaFX.
I have tried using controlsFX CheckListView but there is a known bug preventing event handlers from binding after you reset the CheckListView. I need the event handler to trigger and save the state of the List so that users can undo changes. I have also found a question that is identical to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297104/javafx-8-listview-with-checkboxes-scrollpane-issue), but no proper solution was provided or I am missing something.

To make sure my problem is clear: I tick "Liver" in the list, scroll to look at other items in the list, then when I scroll back up "Liver" is unchecked and no change event was triggered to indicate that the value of the CheckBox has changed.

Comment: The answer in the question you linked should work fine. The problem is you have no means of storing the data for which items are selected and which are not. You need some kind of collection of `OrganEnum` to represent this, which is how the question you linked is structured.

Comment: Okay awesome I think I get it now, thanks for the reply. @James_D